# Grant permission java.lang.RuntimePermission modify thread

Tags: java, multithreading, security

How can I grant permission `java.lang.RuntimePermission "modifyThread";`

I tried editing in `C:\ede-5.1.1\java6-ibm-sr4ifx3-2009-06-22\jre\lib\security` `under java.policy` But when I started my application after editing, I am still getting the same error I was getting previously. Is there anything else that I have to do after modifying the java.policy?

Comment: *"How can I.."*  Why would you want to?

Comment: I am using ThreadPoolExecutor under SecurityManager so always I am getting errors so for that reason I want to grant permission.

Comment: More specifically, why do you want to modify threads?  What feature does that provide to the user?

Comment: Actually i cannot shutdown my own executors under Security Manager. So for that I guess I need to modify the java.policy right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually programs which choose to execute using a SecurityManager use a custom policy file.  this is often specified on the commandline.  if so, then you should be editing that file.

also, you said you edited the file, but did not indicate how you modified it.

Comment: Can you suggest me how should I edit the file from the command line as I have no clue. Previously I went to java.policy file and copy pasted this line `permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "modifyThread";` in `grant { }`.

Comment: @Nevzz03 - i didn't say you need to edit the file from the command line.  i mean, you should see if a policy file is specified on the command line and _edit that file_.